# How can I update my object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In this simple script, I try to change the value of the string contained in `a.person`.  Why does it not update the `object.property`'s value?

```js
function searchObject(object, value) {

  object = value;

}

var a = {
  person: "Ian"
};

searchObject(a.person, "James");

document.write(a.person);
```

I thought that the output should be "James", not "Ian".  Why does it not update my object?

Comment: You give the function just a string and not an object or something. So how should it get the reference to the parent object anyhow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing now is replacing the local variable `object` with the value `value`. What you could do instead to achieve this is:

```js
function searchObject(object, property, value) {
  object[property] = value;
}

var a = {
  person: "Ian"
};

searchObject(a, 'person', "James");

document.write(a.person);
```

Then you wouldn't be replacing the local variable, but the property of the object. The object still refers to the same thing, and in this code, you're editing the object, instead of locally replacing it.

This is because in JavaScript, every function argument is passed by value, but since objects are stored as pointers, not as their value, that means that you're only given the memory address of the object if you put `a` in your function parameter. If you then access that variable within the function again, it will be a pointer to the same thing. Changing properties in it then will change the properties in the actual object too.

Comment: Wow.  We both posted literally the same answer at almost the same time :-D

Comment: Yep :P, you ninja'd me by 7 seconds.

Comment: You're answer is accurate, but I would just mention that `object[property] = value` is a pretty concise syntax to get the job done. It's not necessary to wrap it in a function.

Comment: @rblakeley while that is true, I'd assume this is just a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and more is actually done with this object in the function. You are completely right though.

Answer (score 4):

This is because only objects are passed by reference.  Everything else is passed by value.  If you wanted this to work, you could try this:

```js
function searchObject(object, key, value) {
  object[key] = value;
}

var a = {
  person: "Ian"
};

searchObject(a, "person", "James");

document.write(a.person);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in `a.person` as the object, but `a.person` is a string value. Strings are passed by value in JavaScript, not by reference. This means that the `object` in your function is essentially a copy of the string `"Ian"` and not the actual value of `a.person`

Comment: This is mostly true, but not entirely. Everything in JS is passed by reference, but the difference is that in JS, objects are *pointers*, while strings and integers aren't. Even if `a.person` was an array, doing `object = value` in the function would still not work.

Comment: Very true. I was trying to get at that with the "essentially" a copy, but it probably needed the additional clarity.